# Blacklisted IP check service

Tags: ip-address, blacklist

Would you please let me know some API that will check an IP address against spam database?

I do not like users to land on the registration or any form filling web pages if their REMOTE_ADDR is listed in blacklists.

Q #1: Can the spammers disguise their REMOTE_ADDR?

Q #2: Does any API exists to intake the IP Address and return pass/fail flag after checking if the supplied IP was already in the blacklist?

Answer (score 0):

To check list of IP addresses are blacklisted or not, use "whoisthisip's blacklist checker tool.

https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/ (this one is provided by Google and is used by Chrome to check for malicious web hosts)

Also go through this to secure your application from extrnal or blacklisted attack
http://blog.art-of-coding.eu/implementing-a-web-application-firewall/